# Pass environment variable to docker container in circleCI

Tags: docker, circleci

I'm having a bit of difficulty in trying to set up circleCI for a project. I have an app that needs to interact with a couple of custom docker images (and need to connect to the ports, which precludes running the custom containers within the primary container). I'd like to pass a circleCI environment variable `CREDENTIALS` (containing gcloud credentials) to an environment variable of one of the docker images. As interpolation is not supported there I have tried using parameters, but still all that gets passed is the name of the parameter, rather than its value.

A trimmed-down version of the `config.yml` is:

```
version: 2.1

orbs:
  gcp-cli: circleci/gcp-cli@1.3.0

jobs:
  test:
    parameters:
      gcloud_cred:
        type: env_var_name
        default: CREDENTIALS
    docker:
      - image: circleci/python:3.6.4
      - image: custom_image_1:latest
        environment:
          ENV: test
      - image: custom_image_2:latest
        name: database
        environment:
          GCLOUD_CREDENTIALS: << parameters.gcloud_cred >>

    working_directory: ~/app

    steps:
      - checkout
      - setup_remote_docker      
      - run:
          name: do the rest
          command: |
            sh do_all_stuff.sh
workflows:
  version: 2.1

  test:
    jobs:
      - test:
          gcloud_cred: CREDENTIALS
```

I have tried other combinations such as using `${CREDENTIALS}` in the workflow and a string-type parameter, but everytime in `custom_image_2` the env variable `GCLOUD_CREDENTIALS` just has the value `CREDENTIALS`, and I obviously don't want to hardcode the value into the config.

If anyone knows a way to make this work, or an alternative workaround to be able to pass the value it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize ?